# nginx config exec lua script fail

Tags: nginx, lua, centos

centos 7.4
on my centos. i exec lua script success and get right response from redis.
but in nginx, i config

```
location /lua {
    default_type text/html;
    set_by_lua_file $sum /etc/nginx/conf.d/juices_redirect.lua;
    echo "sum = $sum, user=$user";
}
```

get 500 when i request host/lua.

lua script is

```
package.path = package.path..";/root/redis-lua/src/?.lua"
local ngx = require("ngx")
local redis = require("redis")
local client = redis.connect("127.0.0.1",6379)
client:auth("11111")
a = client:get("id")
return a
```

i really want get your help. thanks

Comment: What does the error.log day?

Comment: i solve this problem.from error.log.i miss install luasocket package. you can install from this article. [link](https://www.sa60.com/post-293.html). and your code contain package path like `package.path = package.path..";/root/redis-lua/src/?.lua"
package.path = package.path..";/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;;"
package.cpath = package.cpath..";/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/?.so;;"`